# Entity Framework Navigation Properties looping issue though WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, code-first, infinite-loop

I have a model like

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nickname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Memberships { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public long GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Members { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public DataContext()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Memberships)
        .WithMany(t => t.Members)
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            x.MapRightKey("GroupId");
            x.ToTable("GroupMembers");
        });
    }
}
```

All goes fine when accessing the entities using a test console application, but I need to have this through a WCF service, here I got this exception:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service

The only way I found to have this working is, removing the navigator in one of the entities, because having the navigators in both sides causes a infinite looping.

Is there a way to have this working without removing the navigators?

Comment: Can you post the code of the service method that is bombing out? Also, can you post the details of the exception that you are getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues if you try to use WCF:

- First issue: Do you want to return related entities as well? Always turn off lazy loading when working with WCF / serialization and make sure that you manually use Include for relations you really want to return. Otherwise lazy loading will load all relation in the object graph. Moreover depending on the way how your service handles context's life cycle, the lazy loading can happen when the context is already disposed.
- You must tell serializer about the circular reference or remove the circular reference. WCF by default uses `DataContractSerializer`. To remove the circular reference you can mark one of those navigation properties with `IgnoreDataMember` attribute or you can simply tell serializer about the circular reference by marking all entities with `DataContract(IsReference = true)` attribute and all member properties which should be serialized with `DataMember` attribute.

Comment: Is this still valid in EF6? I see your reply is a bit dated by now. Also, since I'm using autogenerated classes from DB and not Code First method, there's always this issue with overwriting the data model. How do we cope with that? (Partial classes are great but don't resolve the attributing issue.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: If your classes are autogenerated by T4 template you can modify the template directly to produce attributes you need. That will ensure the attributes will be in place every time the model regenerates.