# Multiple Entity Framework Tables Breaking WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I didnt think I was crazy so I went back and made a sample project to reproduce and show what going on.

I have 4 simple projects like below

[image]

I add the EDMX to the Data Project

[image]

Here is my Table Structure

[image]

Here is the properties of the EDMX

[image]

And the generated class

[image]

Add a Reference to the WCF Service Library to the Data project

[image]

Test the Wcf Client with the default tests

[image]

Add a Wcf Method

[image]

And her it is asking for a EF6 Reference

[image]

After Adding the reference My method is like this

[image]

Running the Test Client again I get this exception

[image]

So I copy the connection string from the Data.Edmx project and add it to the WCF project

and run the test client and get a return of this with only one table in the EDMX which is correct.

[image]

But when I update the model and add multiple tables like normal it breaks.  So I just added 1 more table(like below) it breaks with this error. And it is with any tables. More than one table in the model and it will not work.

Is there a step I am missing?  Or why are multiple tables breaking WCF with EF6.1?

[image]

[image]

EDIT This breaks it as well

[image]

With classes like

```
public partial class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Categories1 = new HashSet<Category>();
        this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is when the WCF call is returning, it attempts to serialize the objects (which includes the navigation properties as well).

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

AND

```
public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories1 { get; set; }
public virtual Category Category1 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

If you don't need Navigation properties you can simply mark them as private OR internal.

You can also look into this link for more detail [Entity Framework Navigation Properties looping issue though WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715120/entity-framework-navigation-properties-looping-issue-though-wcf)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to approach it in case where the navigational properties need to be exposed? If I want to keep them as *public* (and, of course, use *Include()*), the serialization still breaks for me. Right now I handle it by creating a copy of everything that I emit and in there create/add new instances that need to be exposed. Very work-around'ish and Q&D in my view.

Comment: Dude, I would give you 20 points for this answer if I could. I chased this problem for 5 days to no avail. Awesome answer that I cannot thank you enough for!